# Adding a Conditional to a Filter function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an object array called filteredAnimals that returns the animals which are present in a given filter.

```
 if (!dog.present) {
    filteredAnimals = filteredAnimals.filter(
      e => !e.animal_type.includes('Dog'),
    );
  }

 if (!cat.present) {
    filteredAnimals = filteredAnimals.filter(
      e => !e.animal_type.includes('Cat'),
    );
  }

 if (!fish.present) {
    filteredAnimals = filteredAnimals.filter(
      e => !e.animal_type.includes('fish'),
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to combine this in one call? I'm a bit stumped because the call won't be made unless the conditional is met. I was thinking of making a function but I feel there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Are `"Dog"`, `"Cat"` and `"fish"` the only conditions that will be filtered? Why is there a comma `,` following `.includes()`?

Comment: oh for some reason my code worked but that shouldn't be in there thanks

Comment: @guest271314 Trailing commas in parameter lists are permitted (style is just rare)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use three conditions:

```
const finalFilteredAnimals = filteredAnimals.filter(({ animal_type }) => (
  (dog.present || !animal_type.includes('Dog')) &&
  (cat.present || !animal_type.includes('Cat')) &&
  (fish.present || !animal_type.includes('fish'))
));
```

Note that it would be better if `dog`, `cat`, and `fish` were in a larger object, say `animals`, so that you could iterate over an array of `['Dog', 'Cat', 'fish']` instead:

```
const finalFilteredAnimals = filteredAnimals.filter(({ animal_type }) => (
  ['Dog', 'Cat', 'fish'].every(animName => (
    animal[animName].present || !animal_type.includes(animName)
  ))
));
```

Comment: so I have a question, the code above doesn't work. When the dog.present is not present it should show cat and fish.  But the filter above sets it so that if dog is not present the result outputs only dogs. I think it has something to do with the &&

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!